# How to add svm on top of cnn as final classifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, keras, svm, sentiment-analysis

I work on sentiment analysis task and i want to add SVM layer on top CNN as a final classifier, how can i do that without using hing-loss?

```
tweet_input = Input(shape=(seq_len,), dtype='int32')

tweet_encoder = Embedding(vocabulary_size, EMBEDDING_DIM, 
input_length=seq_len, trainable=True)(tweet_input)
bigram_branch = Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, padding='same', 
activation='relu', strides=1)(tweet_encoder)
bigram_branch = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(bigram_branch)
trigram_branch = Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', 
activation='relu', strides=1)(tweet_encoder)
trigram_branch = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(trigram_branch)
fourgram_branch = Conv1D(filters=16, kernel_size=4, padding='same', 
activation='relu', strides=1)(tweet_encoder)
fourgram_branch = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(fourgram_branch)
merged = concatenate([bigram_branch, trigram_branch, fourgram_branch], axis=1)
merged = Dense(512, activation='softmax')(merged)
merged = Dropout(0.8)(merged)
merged = Dense(2)(merged)
output = Activation('sigmoid')(merged)
model = Model(inputs=[tweet_input], outputs=[output])

adam=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False)
model.compile(loss='hinge',
              optimizer= adam,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

Comment: Just use pipelines and svm classifier from scikit-learn and Keras wrappers for the scikit-learn API  https://keras.io/scikit-learn-api/

Comment: Is this the sane as i save features from final sigmoid dense and classify it with svm or the feature extracted after fully connected ?? This is the same you talk about or not ??

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but yes it's something like this: you take extracted features, say 512 dim vectors, and use it as inputs for an SVM classifier. I suggest using scikit-learn and before mentioned Keras wrappers as it will allow you to easily optimize model hyperparameters and save/load the entire pretrained model. Btw, you have to change an activation function in the `merged = Dense(512, activation='softmax')(merged)` line to `relu` or something - `softmax` doesn't fit here.

Comment: @constt sorry but i miss understand can you give me example where i add svm classifier exactly and how use it ??

Comment: Sorry, I gave you wrong advice last time. Now I see, such model won't be end-to-end trainable. As I see, the only way to make it end-to-end is to stick to `hinge` loss as you do. You're doing it right, just fix the activation function I mentioned before and you're good to go.

Comment: Hinge loss is part of what makes SVM SVM... If you use something else it is not really SVM anymore

Comment: I need to add svm as layer as final classifier  that use the feature extracted from cnn to increase accuracy.. is this done by hinge loss

Comment: @AsmaaM.Elmohamady did you solve this?

Comment: @patti_jane noo